# Read next line in Text file C Programming

Tags: c, text-files

I know about ***fscanf(), fgets()*** and those other functions to read the next line of a text file. However, if you are given a text file by ***'cat msg1.txt | ./anonymizer'*** would you use the same functions?
For my program the code for the main is:

```
int main (void)
{
    char input[1000]= {'\0'}; //the sentence the user will enter
    printf("Enter a sentence:");
    scanf("%[^\n]", input);
    char newSentence[1000]={'\0'};
    sentence=(char *) &newSentence;
    line=getText(input,0);
    divide(input);
    printf("%s\n",sentence);
    return 0;
}
```

In the command line I enter:

```
gcc -o anonymizer anonymizer.c
cat msg1.txt | ./anonymizer
```

My msg1 text file contains:

> Hi, my email addresses are h.potter@hogwarts.edu and 1a@2b3c@lkj@
>   Although it's not an email addresses, I'd hate if@ you saw my
>   secret@word. Gary.zenkel@nbcuni.comHoever, input variable only
>   contains the first line: 'Hi, my email addresses are
>   h.potter@hogwarts.edu and 1a@2b3c@lkj@'

**How can I get the input variable to contain the other two lines?**

Comment: This program will overrun the `input` buffer and probably crash when given an input with long lines. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302255/

Answer (score 0):

Almost. While it may not actually be defined in such a way, `scanf(...)` is essentially equivalent to `fscanf(stdin, ...)`. Similar for `gets`/`fgets`. You should be able to use either to read from your standard input stream.

Answer (score 0):

To my limited knowledge (I could be wrong), with the standard libc, there are no efficient ways to read a line when you do not know the max line length. You may get memory overflow with `scanf()` and `gets()` because they do not check the length of your buffer. If you use `fgets()`, you may waste time on frequent `strlen()` and `realloc()`. If you use `fgetc()`, it will be slow as `fgetc()` has a huge overhead.

For efficient line reading, we have to keep some intermediate information. It is not that easy. I am attaching an implementation. It is quite complicated, but it is very efficient and generic. If you do not care about the details, you may just focus on the `main()` function about how to use the routines.

To try this program:

```
gcc -Wall prog.c; ./a.out < input.txt > output.txt
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef kroundup32
#define kroundup32(x) (--(x), (x)|=(x)>>1, (x)|=(x)>>2, (x)|=(x)>>4, (x)|=(x)>>8, (x)|=(x)>>16, ++(x))
#endif

#define kstype_t FILE* // type of file handler
#define ksread_f(fp, buf, len) fread((buf), 1, (len), (fp)) // function to read a data chunk

typedef struct {
    int l, m; // l: length of string; m: allocated size
    char *s; // string
} kstring_t;

typedef struct {
    kstype_t f; // file handler
    int begin, end, is_eof, bufsize;
    unsigned char *buf; // buffer
} kstream_t;

kstream_t *ks_open(kstype_t fp, int bufsize)
{
    kstream_t *ks;
    ks = (kstream_t*)calloc(1, sizeof(kstream_t));
    ks->bufsize = bufsize;
    ks->buf = (unsigned char*)malloc(bufsize);
    ks->f = fp;
    return ks;
}

void ks_close(kstream_t *ks)
{
    free(ks->buf); free(ks);
}

int ks_readline(kstream_t *ks, int delimiter, kstring_t *str)
{
    str->l = 0;
    if (ks->begin >= ks->end && ks->is_eof) return -1;
    for (;;) {
        int i;
        if (ks->begin >= ks->end) {
            if (!ks->is_eof) {
                ks->begin = 0;
                ks->end = ksread_f(ks->f, ks->buf, ks->bufsize);
                if (ks->end < ks->bufsize) ks->is_eof = 1;
                if (ks->end == 0) break;
            } else break;
        }
        for (i = ks->begin; i < ks->end; ++i)
            if (ks->buf[i] == delimiter) break;
        if (str->m - str->l < i - ks->begin + 1) {
            str->m = str->l + (i - ks->begin) + 1;
            kroundup32(str->m);
            str->s = (char*)realloc(str->s, str->m);
        }
        memcpy(str->s + str->l, ks->buf + ks->begin, i - ks->begin);
        str->l = str->l + (i - ks->begin);
        ks->begin = i + 1;
        if (i < ks->end) break;
    }
    if (str->s == 0) {
        str->m = 1;
        str->s = (char*)calloc(1, 1);
    }
    str->s[str->l] = '\0';
    return str->l;
}

int main()
{
    kstream_t *ks;
    kstring_t str;
    str.l = str.m = 0; str.s = 0; // initialize the string struct
    ks = ks_open(stdin, 4096); // initialize the file handler
    while (ks_readline(ks, '\n', &str) >= 0) // read each line
        puts(str.s); // print it out
    ks_close(ks); free(str.s); // free
    return 0;
}
```