# What should I use, instead of gets?

Tags: c, gets

There is a finished project, which is not mine. It works well, but if I build, I get a warning:

`the 'gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.`

I have to now fix the project, but I have no idea, how to replace this function

Comment: Try [searching stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302255/c-scanf-vs-gets-vs-fgets) or [the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+to+use+instead+of+gets&oq=what+to+use+instead+of+gets&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.5279j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `fgets()` on the `stdin` stream.

Note that unlike `gets()`, `fgets()` will not remove the newline character at the end of the input if it will fit in the buffer.

If stripping the newline and handling behaviour when input exceeds the provided buffer you might write a wrapper such as:

```
char* read_line( char* buffer, size_t buffer_len )
{
    char* line = fgets( buffer, buffer_len, stdin ) ;
    char* nl = strchr( buffer, '\n' ) ;
    if( nl != 0 )
    {
        // Replace newline character with nul
        *nl = 0 ;
    } 
    else
    {
        // If buffer was shorter than the line - read and discard rest of line.
        while( getchar() != '\n' ) { \* do nothing*\ }
    }

    return line ;
}
```

Comment: Hi Clifford, I'm trying to understand - is there a reason it fills the buffer AND returns the line? Could the function be written to return void?

Comment: @Grandclosing :  Of course, but returning a value costs nothing and allows the function call to be used as an argument directly e.g: `process_line( read_line( buffer, sizeof(buffer) ) ;` - if you don't want to use the return value, just ignore it - it need not be assigned to anything or used an argument.  For example when was the last time you used the return value from `printf()`? Or even noticed it had one!?

Comment: Good point there! I just looked up printf, I can't believe I never noticed that. Thanks!

Comment: The condition in the `while` seems to be wrong :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala : Only 6 years to spot that!

Comment: Well, now that I think about it, strange things can happen if last line has more than buffer_len - 1 characters and there is no line terminator on the last line :D

Comment: Sorry if I didn't understand this, but how does line get returned with newline removed ? Does it happen at *nl = 0 ? Also, what does "If buffer shorter than line mean ?  Thank you in advance, I am trying to understand for the C class.

Comment: @SunnyAk : re. Removing the newline; exactly as the comment states.  Regarding the buffer length read the library docs for `fgets`; if no newline is buffered, the input was longer than the buffer length, and the input buffer needs emptying.