# getline: identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, getline

I have problem with `getline()`.

I tried many examples and read other solutions, but that didn't solve my problem. I still have information `'getline: identifier not found'`.

I included
 `<stdio.h> <tchar.h> <iostream> <conio.h> <stdlib.h> <fstream>` and still nothing.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    cout << "You entered: " << line << endl;
}
```

What do I need to do now?

I use Windows 7 64 bit and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: `<string>` would be the file in which you find [**`std::getline`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: Wildly guessing is not a good way to do programming. What prevented  you from simply looking this up in the documentation?

Answer (score 40):

Get used to simply *reading the documentation* for the language features that you use.
cppreference is quite clear that [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) may found in `string`.

```
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 6):

This should fix that:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
   string line;
   getline(cin, line);
   cout << "You entered: " << line << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <string>
```

Incidentally, "Murach's C++ Programming" textbook incorrectly states that getline() is in the iostream header (p. 71) which may lead to some confusion.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use

```
#include "string"
```

Read: *[std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)*

Comment: Not `"string"` but `<string>` and I am having this problem as well having utilized [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)