# Why is this statement printed twice in while loop?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, io, getchar

I wrote this simple program for practise:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CLASSES 3
#define STUDENTS 4
int grades[CLASSES][STUDENTS];

int main(void)
{
    int i = 1;
    char t,k;
    while(i == 1)
    {
        printf("\n\n\nMENU:\nEnter the grades(E)\nReport Grades(R)\nQuit(Q)\nYour choice: ");
        k = toupper(getchar());
        printf("Input entered... %c\n", k);
        switch(k) {
            case 'E' : 
                printf("Entering the grades..\n");
                break;
            case 'R' :
                printf("Reporting the grades...\n");
                break;
            case 'Q' :
                printf("Quitting the program...\n");
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                printf("ERROR: %c: Incorrect menu option\n", k);
                break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, it first asks me to enter a choice. If I enter 'E' or 'R', it goes into the respective 'case' block but in the next iteration within the while loop, it doesn't wait for me to enter my choice. Instead it assumes I entered "NULL" and asks for my prompt third time. This keeps happening everytime I enter a choice. Here is the output of this program. What am I missing here?

```
host-mb:c_practice host$ ./asd



MENU:
Enter the grades(E)
Report Grades(R)
Quit(Q)
Your choice: E
Input entered... E
Entering the grades..



MENU:
Enter the grades(E)
Report Grades(R)
Quit(Q)
Your choice: Input entered...

ERROR:
: Incorrect menu option



MENU:
Enter the grades(E)
Report Grades(R)
Quit(Q)
Your choice: R
Input entered... R
Reporting the grades...



MENU:
Enter the grades(E)
Report Grades(R)
Quit(Q)
Your choice: Input entered...

ERROR:
: Incorrect menu option



MENU:
Enter the grades(E)
Report Grades(R)
Quit(Q)
Your choice: Q
Input entered... Q
Quitting the program...
host-mb:c_practice host$
```

Comment: Because you pressed e, then pressed enter. That's two characters.

Comment: `k = toupper(getchar());` --> `k = toupper(getchar());getchar();` one for newline.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because you type a letter and then you press enter. Use another `getchar()` to eat the trailing newline.

So change this:

```
k = toupper(getchar());
```

to this:

```
k = toupper(getchar());
getchar(); // eat the trailing newline
```

When the user inputs something, it goes to the **stdin** (standard input) stream and the system makes sure to store what the user typed in a internal buffer. So here is what happened with *your* code:

[image]

So the solution is to **eat the trailing newline**!

---

Easter eggs tips:

You should receive this:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’
```

because you lack of the IO header, thus you should add in the top of your main file this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Similarly you should add:

```
#include <ctype.h>  // for toupper()
#include <stdlib.h> // for exit()
```

Another solution would be to use [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), see this question for more [C - scanf() vs gets() vs fgets()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302255/c-scanf-vs-gets-vs-fgets).

---

I had a similar issue to yours with `scanf()` and I was in your shoes, so I had written down the [solution](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/) at the time.

Comment: That helped. Thanks. So everytime I expect an "enter" from the user, I need to eat it using getchar().

Comment: Exactly! Nice catch and nice question, you got my +1. @gixxer

Comment: I guess there is another solution, instead of using getchar() 2 times, I can use gets() and strip the '\n' from the input.

Comment: Correct @gixxer, see my edit! Use `fgets()` instead!

Comment: @gixxer you probably got it by now, but I added a pic that I believe will help future readers, hope you like it! :D

Comment: @gixxer Actually, double `getchar()` call may be very unwise. If a user enters 0 or 2+ characters and then presses enter, the program will start to behave strangely. So, it's better to use this `k = toupper(getchar()); if (k != '\n') while (getchar() != '\n') {}` or [f]gets() call.