# Remove characters from string in C

Tags: c, string, memcpy

I'm having an issue removing characters from a string. I have been able to identify the characters to remove and store them as a new string but I would like a code that enables me to remove the new string's characters from the original string (where I've labelled as xxxxxxxx).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char input[120], to_del[120], new_input[120];
int a,b;


void removeString();

int main(void)
{
    printf("\nEnter your sentence: ");
    gets(input);

    printf("\nWhere to start: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("\nHow many characters to delete: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    removeString();

    printf("\nNew sentence: %s\n",new_input);

    return ;
}

void removeString()
{
    memcpy(to_del, &input[a-1], b);
    new_input [strlen(input)-b] =xxxxxxxx;
    return ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT in response to @SouravGhosh comment, about overlapping strings. First I copy the string to `new_input` and then copy the right hand part back to `input` to overwrite the section which must be removed.

```
int len = strlen(input);
strcpy(new_input, input);
if (a < len && a+b <= len)
    strcpy (input + a, new_input + a + b);
```

I notice the rest of your code doesn't check anything is happening correctly, such as the return value from `scanf`, and please note `gets` is dangerous: it is better to use `fgets` with `stdin`.

The `strcpy` instruction copies the right-hand part of the string over the part you want removed. It works by using pointer arithmetic. Adding `a` to `input` is the same as getting the address of `input[a]`, the place where you want the removal to begin. Similary `new_input[a+b]` is the start of the right hand part you wish to keep.

The point of the `if` condition, is that if `a` isn't within the string, or if the part you want removed overflows the end of the string, it can't be done.

Comment: please explain the strcpy statement and how the if condition affects it. I'm really new to c programming. Also, doesn't 'void' at the start of each function mean that a return value becomes redundant?

Comment: heh? Please correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this (as shown in your code) the ideal way of source and destination buffer overlap?

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes you are right - it's supposed to be Undefined Behaviour, so `memmove` should be used. But I have always assumed the UB applies when the strings overlap the other way.

Comment: @NathanPiper I amended the answer, and explained more.

Answer (score 0):

You can take following approach

1. copy from index `0` to `a-1` of `input` to `new_input`
2. copy from index `a+b-1` to end  of `input` to `new_input`

Finaly, your `new_input` will have all the values between position `a` and `b` removed.

Note:

1. using `gets()` is dangerous. Use `fgets()` instead.
2. You cannnot *assign* strings using `=` in c. You need to copy the string containts using `strcpy()`/`memcpy()`.

Comment: fgets needs more arguments plus everything is working fine right now. Out of curiousity, in which situation could gets() be dangerous

Comment: @NathanPiper see the answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3302255/2173917) for a detailed discussion on the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
void removeString(void);

int main(void){
    printf("\nEnter your sentence: ");
    scanf("%119[^\n]%*c", input);

    printf("\nWhere to start(1 origin): ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\nHow many characters to delete: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    removeString();

    printf("\nOriginal sentence: %s\n", input);
    printf("\nNew sentence: %s\n", new_input);
    printf("\nLabelled sentence: %s\n", to_del);

    return 0;
}

void removeString(void){
    strcpy(new_input, input);
    memmove(&new_input[a-1], &new_input[a -1 + b], strlen(&new_input[a -1 + b])+1);

    strcpy(to_del, input);
    memset(&to_del[a-1], 'x', b);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I should have said originally that I require the code without memmove.

Comment: @NathanPiper `memcpy(new_input, input, &input[a] - input - 1); memcpy(&new_input[a-1], &input[a -1 + b], strlen(&input[a -1 + b])+1);`