# Store user input in a variable so that I can get a substring from it

Tags: c

In C Programming, how do I store user input in a variable so that I can get a substring from it?
When typing in "hello Point" in the console I get an error: The substring is NULL. This means my word variable is empty? What exactly did I do wrong and why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
   char word[100];

   printf ("Enter a word: ");
   scanf ("%s", word);
   const char needle[] = "Point";
   char *ret;

   ret = strstr(word, needle);

   printf("The substring is: %s\n", ret);
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: "What exactly did I do wrong?" You tried to print `ret` without checking that it isn't `NULL`, which is a valid (and likely) return value of `strstr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strstr` returns `NULL` if the substring is not found. This is the case here. You are using `scanf` to read string. It will stop scanning after first occurrence of a white space, an `' '` here. Therefore, only `hello` will be stored in `word` and `strstr(word, needle)` will return `NULL`.

Use `fgets` instead to read string.

```
fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use magic numbers. I think `fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);` is better usage of `fgets()`.

Comment: @haccks im between MikeCATs and your solution. What the advantage and disadvantages of both solutions?

Comment: @Asperger; Using `fgets` over `scanf` to read string is always safe. For detailed explanation read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3302594/2455888).

Comment: Where do I put my needle variables within fgets? word is the sentence but its not looking for anything in the sentence

Comment: @Asperger; Just replace the statement `scanf ("%s", word);` with `fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);`. That's it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I replaced the wrong line. It works now. Why do so many people use scanf? Even my teacher

Comment: In the beginning almost everyone starts with `scanf`. Now you learned about `fgets` so you should use it from now :)

Answer (score 3):

`%s` for `scanf()` stops reading when it found a whitespace.

Try using `scanf ("%99[^\n]", word);` instead. (added `99` to avoid buffer overrun)

Comment: Can you please explain how that part works? %99[^\n]

Comment: `%[\n]` is "read characters until a newlline character (or EOF) is found".

Comment: So is it some sort of regular expression?

Comment: @Asperger : `99` is the limit of the number of characters copied to the buffer. `[^\n]` sets the input delimiter to <newline> rather than the default which is any whitespace character (space, tab, newline etc. ).  At this point you might refer to the documentation for `scanf()`.  In this case you might alternatively use `fgets()`.

Comment: @Asperger : No, it is not as flexible as *regular expressions*, it just sets the delimiter.