# Not able to replace a character in a string with another string

Tags: c, string, replace

Here's a question where we need to replace all occurences of a character in a string with another new string.
Given below is the question:

Write a program that replaces the occurence of a given character (say c)
in a primary string (say PS) with another string (say s).

Input:
The first line contains the primary string (PS)
The next line contains a character (c)
The next line contains a string (s)

Output:
Print the string PS with every occurence of c replaced by s.

NOTE:
- There are no whitespaces in PS or s. 
- Maximum length of PS is 100.
- Maximum length of s is 10.

Below is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ps[100],*ptr,c,s[10];

    printf("Enter any string:");
    gets(ps);

    printf("Enter the character you want to replace:");
    scanf("%c",&c);

    printf("Enter the new string:");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",&s);

    ptr=ps;

    while(*ptr!='\0')
    {
        if(*ptr==c)
        *ptr=s;
        ptr++;
    }

    printf("Final string is:");
    puts(ps);
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to replace a character with a string. It just gives me a garbage output in place of the character that I want to replace.

But, when I declare it as a character, the output is as expected. It replaces the character with another character.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` and `gets()`...both are bad.

Comment: the 'garbage' you see is probably a memory address ...

Comment: I recommend writing the resulting string to a new `char` array. Arrays in `c` don't automatically resize. Even if you were correctly replacing the character `c` with the string `s`, if `s` is more than one character long it's going to overwrite characters in `ps` ,, that's not what you want. You can certainly move characters around in the array to make room for the new ones, but that's going to be more difficult coding-wise than simply writing to a new array.

Comment: Also `&s` -> `s` in *`scanf("%s", &s)`*

Comment: Your compiler should warn you in this line: `*ptr = s;`. It's actually an error.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `scanf("%s", &s)`  works anyway.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Certinaly common to "work", yet must `scanf("%s", &s)` work as it is passing the wrong type of pointer?  (pointer to an array versus a pointer to `char`)

Comment: `&s` passes a pointer of incompatible type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*ptr=s;` in

```
if(*ptr==c)
    *ptr=s;
```

is really assigning the base address of the character array `s` to the memory location being pointed to by `ptr`. That doesn't replace the character with string but will lead to error.

I agree with [yano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3476780/yano). It would be better to create a new character array to store the resultant string as the original array may not have enough space to hold the new one.

If the new string is `result`, you could do something like

```
for(i=j=0; ps[i]!='\0'; ++i)
{
    result[j++]=ps[i];
    if(ps[i]==c)
    {
        for(--j, k=0; s[k]!='\0'; ++k)
        {
            result[j++]=s[k];
        }
    }
}
result[j]=0;
```

The `scanf("%s",&s);` should be made `scanf("%s", s);` as the name of an array [decays into a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641963/5375464) to its first element.

It's better to avoid `gets()` and `fflush(stdin)` as [Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh) mentioned.

`fgets()` is safer than `gets()` [because you can guarantee you never overflow the input string buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303445/5375464).

As for `fflush(stdin)` being wrong, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).

Answer (score 3):

In C, a string is a sequence of characters, represented by the address of the first.  So `*ptr = s` should have gotten you a warning about mismatched types from the compiler.  If you want to insert a string into another, you'll need to move the other characters around to make room for it.

But your problem description does not seem to *require* that you make a new string, just print *as if* you had.  So you could loop through the original string, and for each character, if it is to be replaced, print the replacement string, otherwise print the original character.

Comment: Could improve this: "In C, a string is a sequence of characters, represented by the address of the first. "   In C, a _string_ is a sequence of characters up to and includes the _null character_.  A _string_ is more like an array than an address.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I change my code? Should I determine the new string length and create those many spaces after the character to be replaced? If yes, how do I do so?