# Second string not getting scanned

Tags: c, string, scanf, c-strings

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()    
{

  char str1[100];    
  char str2[100];

  printf("\n Enter the first String\n");    
  scanf("%[^\n]s",str1);

  printf("Enter the second String");    
  scanf("%[^\n]s",str2);  

  printf("\n The strings are %s  %d \n",str1,i);     
}
```

Comment: Add fflush(stdout) after first scanf

Comment: Not working!Why do you think this is happening?

Comment: The format you are supplying to scanf is the problem. Using just `%s` will work with strings containing no white spaces, as the man page states: `s - Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to the initial element of a character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence  and  the  terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added automatically.  The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to read a whole line, use `fgets`. At least you have some control over the string length input, and no need to deal with `scanf` peculiarities

```
printf("\n Enter the first String\n");    
fgets(str1, 100, stdin);

printf("Enter the second String");    
fgets(str2, 100, stdin);

printf("\n The strings are %s  %s \n",str1,str2);
```

Note that the trailing `\n` is still in the strings (if they were 98 chars length max).

[Worth reading - scanf vs fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302255/c-scanf-vs-gets-vs-fgets)

Comment: If i am using fgets to scan the string the length turns out to be one more than original length!Please help.

Comment: Got it.Even \n will be added as a character.

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing is you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the `'\n'` stays in `stdin` which is consumed as string in second `scanf()`.

You can put a dummy `getchar()` between two `scanf()`. That will solve the problem because it will consume the `'\n'` that is not consumed by the previous `scanf`.

The way you said that you are reading a `word` - you are basically reading lines seperated by `'\n'`.

A better way would be to use `fgets()`. It serves two way it will solve the `\n` consumption problem and the other thing is `fgets()` will read a line and provides much better control than `scanf()`.

#### "second string not getting scanned"

No. It is not the case, it is reading the `\n` from the previous line you entered.

Also few things you should know about `fgets`. It will consume the `\n` also. So your string will contain the `\n` as character. In case you don't want that   then you can do this

```
str[strcspn(str,"\n")]='\0'
```

---

```
char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);
```

> The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of
>   characters specified by `n` from the stream pointed to by `stream`
>   into the array pointed to by `s`. No additional characters are read
>   after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A
>   null character is written immediately after the last character read
>   into the array.

Also check the return value of `fgets()` to know if it is successful or not.
If the (EOF)End-of-File is encountered and no characters have been read, `fgets` returns `NULL`.
So the code will be

```
if( fgets(str1, 100, stdin) ){
  // successfully read the string.
  str1[strcspn(str1,"\n")]='\0'; ///removing `'\n'`

}
```

So here you can get in input the string but along with that `\n`. We are overwriting it if the call is successful.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAXLEN 100
int main()    
{

  char str1[MAXLEN];    
  char str2[MAXLEN];

  printf("\n Enter the first line\n");    
  if( fgets(str1,MAXLEN,stdin) ){
     str1[strcspn(str1,"\n")]='\0';
  }
  else {
     fprintf(stderr,"Line not read");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  printf("\n Enter the second line\n");
  if( fgets(str2,MAXLEN,stdin) ){
     str2[strcspn(str2,"\n")]='\0';
  }   
  else {
     fprintf(stderr,"Line not read");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } 

  printf("\n The strings are \n(%s)  \n%s \n",str1,str2);  
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;   
}
```