# How to return a string by replacing with another string in c

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>

char str(char *s) {  
    char s1[100];
    printf("another string to replace:");
    scanf("%d",s1);  
    s=s1;  
    return s;
}

void main() {  
    char s[100],s2[100];  
    scanf("%s",s);  
    s2=str(s);  
    printf("%s",s);
}
```

How to return a string by replacing with another string in c??I'm unable to replace the string using functions

Comment: did you mean to print s2?

Comment: yes..................

Comment: you'll probably want to use strcpy https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm

Comment: one thing you need to change is char* str()  you're currently saying it rturns 1 character. You also need to assign the result to a char* s2; in main() and John Boker has good advice.

Comment: tq guys..... :)

Comment: also, be careful with `scanf`. You might consider using `fgets` as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302255/c-scanf-vs-gets-vs-fgets/3302594#3302594

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a several things to say about your code.

1. You can't copy strings using `=`
2. The return type is wrong. Must be `char*`
3. The `scanf` format string is wrong. Use `%s` for strings.
4. You don't need an extra array in the function. Just `scanf` directly into `s`
5. Never do `scanf("%s", ...` Always put a limit to it like `scanf("%99s", ...`

Something like:

```
char* str(char *s) {  
    printf("another string to replace:");
    scanf("%99s",s);  
    return s;
}

void main() {  
    char s[100],s2[100];  
    scanf("%99s",s);    
    strcpy(s2, str(s));  
    printf("%s",s);
}
```

I am, however, not sure what you want the code to do. As it is now `s` and `s2` just end as identical strings.

If you just want a function that can read a new value into `s` it can be done like:

```
void str(char *s) {  
    printf("another string to replace:");
    scanf("%99s",s);  
}

void main() {  
    char s[100];  
    scanf("%99s",s);    
    str(s);
    printf("%s",s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to want to do is copy the values of the characters in `s1` into your `s` variable. not just set one equal to the other. either using `strcpy` or looping through your characters in `s1` and copying them directly to the correct locations in `s`.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm

this works for me without using `strcpy`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void str(char *s) {  
    char s1[100];
    printf("another string to replace:");
    scanf("%s",s1);  
    // not real safe but we know s and s1 have 100 characters.
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        s[i] = s1[i];
    }   
}

int main() {  
    char s[100],s2[100];  
    scanf("%s",s);  
    str(s);  
    printf("%s",s);
}
```