# C: How can I split the user input of a number and store it into an array of elements?

Tags: c

I have a number, 321197186 which the user inputs. How can I store this number into an array one element at a time. Basically, I am trying to store the 1st digit into 0th element and so on. And then I have to do some computation on that number.

Comment: just manage that number as a string when you read it, and that string is your array, after for each char remove `'0'` and you got the digit value to do your computations. An other way is to read char per char etc

Comment: but that wouldn't work right because I cant read the string, I can only read one character at a time.

Comment: so read char par char and remove `'0'` for each to get the digit value, as I said in previous remark

Answer (score 1):

Represent your number as a string, where every character of that string will be the corresponding digit of your number.

There are a plethora of method to read a string, but I suggest you use [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 10

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char number[MAX_LEN];
    printf("Enter a number: \n");
    fgets(number, MAX_LEN , stdin);
    printf("%s\n", number);
    return 0;
}
```

With a for loop, you access the characters (digits) of the string (number) one by one, if you like.

I suggest you also eat the trailing newline that `fgets()` leaves in the input array, as already explained in [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input).

---

Alternative solution proposed by bruno@:

```
scanf("%9s", number);
```

Read more in [C - scanf() vs gets() vs fgets()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302255/c-scanf-vs-gets-vs-fgets/31303445).

Comment: why so complicated when `scanf("%9s", number);`does the work and does not save the possible spaces (in *isspace* definition) before and after ?

Comment: @bruno `scanf()` is more prune to error than `fgets()`, but it's a fair point, I'll add it as an alternative solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have

```
int num;
if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1)
{
    // Input error
    exit(1);
}

// Now the user input is available in num
```

then you do

```
#define MAX_DIGITS 32
int digits[MAX_DIGITS] = { 0 };
int index = 0;
while(num != 0 && index < MAX_DIGITS)
{
    digits[index] = num % 10;
    ++index;
    num = num / 10;
}

// Now the array digits holds the individual digits
// and index holds the number of valid digits
```

Comment: `do {...} (num != 0 && index < MAX_DIGITS);` handle also nicely handles `num == 0`.

Comment: `#define MAX_DIGITS 32` is very large considering you decided to read an *int*, and you do not need to make that kind of assumption because the number of digit of the max int can be known at compile time in several ways

Comment: You also place digits in reverse order than expected

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this logic in C -

```
number = 321197186
while(number> 0)  -  leave if number becomes 0 
{
    int last_digit = number % 10;  - Last digit from the number
    printf("%d",last_digit);  

    number = number / 10;    - to get the remaining number.
}
```

This can be also done in Python as -

```
number = 321197186
list1 = []
for i in str(number):
    list1.append(i)
print(list1)
```

Comment: not sure that helps a lot the OP, you do not put the digits in an array as required, and Python proposal is not requested too

Comment: Thanks for your comment bruno, I think logic is the key and putting the output in an array can be taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

> store this number into an array one element at a time.

Let us take advantage of the input process to have a convenient way to determine the length of input including leading zeros (but not input with a sign, leading spaces) by using `"%n"` to record the offset of the scan.

Use `% 10` to exact the least significant decimal digit of the number.

```
int number;
int offset;
if (scanf("%d%n", &number, &offset) == 1) {
  int a[offset];  // VLA
  while (offset > 0) {
    a[--offset] = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof a/sizeof a[0]; i++) {
    printf("a[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
  }
}
```

Output

```
a[0] = 3
a[1] = 2
a[2] = 1
a[3] = 1
a[4] = 9
a[5] = 7
a[6] = 1
a[7] = 8
a[8] = 6
```

Answer (score -1):

But as bruno points out, you just have to check it as a string as an user input with fgets is an array of characters (even if we are talking about numbers).
For more detail:

```
for(i=0;i<sizeof(array_input);i++){
     //Store the char into another array
}
```