# Is there any way I can print NOT FOUND if the program can't find it?

Tags: c, if-statement

This is my code (Note that I'm on linux) :

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    system("clear");
    char command[300];
start:
    printf("user@clo2>>");
    gets(command);
    if (strcmp(command,"exit")==0){
        system("clear");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (strcmp(command,"--version")==0){
        printf("CLO2 Version : 1.0");
        printf("\n");
        goto start;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the user enters a text that the program can't find then I want it to print the text "NOT FOUND".

Comment: Am I seeing the `gets` function being used here?? I hope that's a typo and you meant `fgets`

Comment: Also, indentation is crucial - this code is unreadable. Consider [GNU indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/).

Comment: @costaparas Pretty sure it's not a typo: `fgets` has 3 arguments.

Comment: And is that a `goto` I see there?

Comment: @ibug yes, indeed, was trying to be "funny"

Comment: When I use gets instead of fgets it works perfectly.

Comment: I suggest compiling with a **recent** version of a compiler, and with some basic compilation flags enabled. Consider `gcc` with `gcc -Wall -Werror`

Comment: The `gets` function is deprecated, and should **not** be used. Please compile with a recent C standard, perhaps `-std=c11` and turn on some basic warnings - you should never use `gets` -- see more in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302255/c-scanf-vs-gets-vs-fgets) post.

Comment: What else can I use instead of gets?

Comment: _If the user enters a text that the program can't find_ , what are the **things** you want to find?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "can't find" ? That there's no executable file corresponding to the first word of the command in the PATH ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `else if` to test each possibility, then use a final `else` for `NOT FOUND`.

Other improvements you should make:

1. Use a loop rather than `goto`.
2. Use `fgets()` rather than `gets()`, which has been removed from the language because it's unsafe.
3. Since `fgets()` leaves the newline in the buffer, you should include that in the strings you compare with.
4. Don't use `exit(1)` unless the program is exiting due to an error. Just break out of the loop.
5. You need `<string.h>` to get the declaration of `strcmp()`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    system("clear");
    char command[300];
    while (1) {
        printf("user@clo2>>");
        fgets(command, sizeof command, stdin);
        if (strcmp(command,"exit\n")==0){
            system("clear");
            break;
        } else if (strcmp(command,"--version\n")==0){
            printf("CLO2 Version : 1.0");
            printf("\n");
        } else {
            printf("NOT FOUND\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To check the value returned by *fgets* allows to manage the EOF case, your program will never end if the input is redirected on a file. The entered commands being on one word `scanf("%299s", command)` seems a better choice than *fgets*. To use *printf* to print a string as it is done or worst a single char is also expensive for nothing. `while (fputs("user@clo2>>", stdout), scanf("%299s", command) == 1) { if ... puts("CLO2 Version : 1.0"); } else { puts("NOT FOUND"); } ..` can be proposed in second choice

Comment: When I press enter then still says command not found. Is there any way I can prevent that from happening?

Comment: Anything other than `exit` or `--version` will say NOT FOUND. If you want to treat an empty input differently, you need to check for that explicitly. Don't forget to include the newline.