# User inputs a sentence (string). How to finish the input with Enter in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, input

I've tried different types of string input(scanf, getchar, gets), but none of them can finish input with Enter. Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: `[Enter]` is a key on a keyboard, not a character. If you mean a newline character for line-based inputs, you can use `fgets`. Never use `gets`. Never.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cheatah said, the function you looking for is `fgets()`. Always try to avoid `gets()` as it offers no protections against a buffer overflow vulnerability and can cause big problems in your program. You can read some of the answers to this question to clarify the utility of each function
[Scanf() vs gets() vs fgets()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302255/c-scanf-vs-gets-vs-fgets)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char str[20];  // String with 19 characters (because last character is null character)

int main() {   
    fgets(str, 20, stdin);  // Read string
    puts(str);  // Print string
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that. To finish the input by pressing Enter, I need to fill all the 19 characters. But how can I finish, if I need to input for example 10 characters?